# Noun meaning "compelling force"

Tags: meaning, nouns, connotation

I am looking for a noun that would refer to a compelling force, but I couldn't find a satisfactory one elsewhere.  The word I thought of was "compellence," but that has [other connotations](http://en.citizendium.org/wiki/Compellence).

The context: some scholars around the world suddenly feel an urge to pursue a course of action handed down by a fictional deity, but not in such a way that the deity identifies himself or that the recipients are aware that the urge has come from some external influence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you mean "[compulsion](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+compulsion&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8)," meaning "an irresistible urge to behave in a certain way."

Comment: I had considered that word, but its connotations all involve acting against one's own wishes.  Unfortunately, that doesn't really line up with what I had in mind.

Comment: "the action or state of forcing or being forced to do something; constraint."

"an irresistible urge to behave in a certain way, especially against one's conscious wishes."

These connotations (doing something that you wish you weren't/didn't have to) are causing a problem for me.

Comment: Then maybe "impetus"?

Comment: I think that's a lot closer to what I had in mind.  Thanks for reminding me of that word!